# "Best" way for loading many items

Tags: android

I'm making an ListView in my app which over time could contain hundreds of items. Are there any "best" methods of loading lots of data?

My idea is to load it in chunks (say 10-20 items). Load the first chunk, then when the user is about halfway through scrolling, load the next chunk, add it to the bottom of the list (and make sure the list scroll offset doesn't jump about).

Some other ideas I had just didn't like so much were accepting the cost of a large http call and load all the data at once, but just load it in chunks as they scroll, or maybe add a "Next x items" button at the bottom, or loading all the items into the list at once and having one large list I don't need to keep track of.

I personally like my original idea, I was just wondering if there is a preferred method or doing this, and if there are any performance issues I could have.

The data in question will be a JSON string, and each item will display some title text, a date, the author of the item, and an image which will be downloaded using the Picasso library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial idea is my preferred approach because it works very well in most situations.

The second one may work well, but the problem is, the "large" data concept is relative across devices. For powerful devices you may load 2000 items at once, but it will kill older, slower phones. Also, if you're loading 2000 items when the use case of that `ListView` is to choose one in the first  100, you are wasting bandwith.

The first approach is very scalable: You really don't care if there are 5 items or 50 million, you just load chunks as the user consumes them. The memory usage is consistent. Coupled with ListView's view recycling, this will have a small memory footprint.

To say something positive about the second approach: Maybe in a use case when the `ListView` always has the same data, and it rarely changes, for example, an image library, you may want to load all the data at application start and cache it, so you never have to do network requests while the user is using the app. If the data size is not huge, I'd go for this second approach. But always having in mind that there's a critical size after which you will need to page!

Comment: Ahh I didn't think about older devices. I think I will go with my first idea because as you say, it's scaleable. Write the logic once, and (hopefully) it will work forever. I just wanted to check what I was doing was going to be a good idea. I might be able to cache certain things but the data will be updated at the latest every 2-3 days, usually a few times per day so I may need to do some testing as to what I could cache.

Comment: so in your case the first approach is definitely the way to go. Implement anyways a sdcard cache with a timeout of maybe a couple hours for the requests, it's really easy to do, and you can save a lot of requests if your users frequently go to that listview!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can load all items once and show them all (if you will use ViewHolder pattern and lazy image loading using Picasso - everything should be ok).
 If you have some business logic which force you to show data by pages - you can follow the way that you described first.
If you will show all data - you can add search by list for better UX(you also can do it when you have pages but it will be more tricky).

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote an article on similar topic:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Batch-loading-list

The article comes also with a small library of common classes.
Maybe you will find it helpful.
Cheers,